# Creating custom list view for Knowledge object

Tags: visualforce, lightning, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I have to create custom list view for knowledge article object in visualforce and lightning. I saw in the document that lightning:listview does not support knowledge object. Can we create it in visualforce page. I cannot see it anywhere.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_knowledge_articleList.htm

Comment: The above one is used for showing a list of knowledge articles. I need to show a list view